# Is List.iterator() thread-safe?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, thread-safety

In Java: Is `List.iterator()` thread-safe, i.e. does the returned iterator reflect the current state of the list at any time or just the state of the list at the time of its creation?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The behaviour of List.iterator() is not defined or consistent with different List implementations.

For ArrayList, LinkedList, you can get a ConcurrentModificationException if the list is modified when you are iterating over it. (This is not guaranteed) The way to avoid this issue is to use a synchronizedList() and lock the list while iterating over it.

For Vector, the collection is synchronized, but the iterator is not thread safe.

For CopyOnWriteArrayList, you get a snapshot of the elements in the list at the time you call iterator(), This iterator is thread safe, and you don't need to use any locking. Note: the contents of the elements can change.

Answer (score 15):

No iterator is thread-safe. If the underlying collection is changed amidst iteration, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Even iterators of synchronized collections are not thread-safe - you have to synchronize manually.

One exception is the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which holds a snapshot during iteration.

Comment: "No iterator is thread safe except one" could have been written as "All are thread safe except two or three" ;)

Comment: If the underlying collection is changed during iteration by another thread, CME may be thrown or may be not thrown, since internal modification counter is not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what class you use,

not for `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());` reason but

for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` reason.

best Description [here](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/understanding-collections-and-thread-safety-in-java)