# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException while iterating this collection?

Tags: java, exception, collections, guava

I need to iterate over a collection of items & sometimes add to that collection at the same time. However, incase I add while iterating then I just start the iteration from fresh by breaking out of iteration loop & restarting iteration from beginning. However this leads to 
`ConcurrentModificationException`. [code below]

```
    List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer lobId: collection) {
         ..
         if (someCondition) {
             collection.add(something); 
             break; 
         }
    }
```

How could I possibly do something like above avoiding `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Would it be correct to simply use an `Array` instead of `ArrayList` to avoid this exception ?
Is there any type of specialized collection for this ?

--

## Edit:

I dont want to create a new copy for this arraylist because I'm repeating this entire iteration process multiple times unless some requirement is completed. Creating a new copy each time would bring in some extra overhead, which I would like to avoid if somehow possible.

Also if possible I would like to maintain a sorted order & unique values in that collection. Is there anything that is ready to use in any library? Otherwise I could sort it at the end of iteration process & remove duplicates. That will also do fine for me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-for-each-loop-in-arraylist

Comment: @user01 modified my response to suit your new requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code cannot lead to ConcurrentModificationException because after you add an element you break the loop and dont use iterator anymore

Comment: But actually it does. But wait.. May be I just simplified it while putting here. It also contained a call to `addAll()` method while iteration.!?

Comment: You removed your answer about listIterator while I was exploring that option, doesn't that hold good ?

Comment: ListIterator.add will actually insert an element at currrent index and it's probably what you dont want

Comment: `"This code cannot lead to ConcurrentModificationException.. "`- yeah I investigated about this & found that I wasn't `break`-ing when doing `<arraylist>.addAll(EMPTY_LIST)` in which case it was leading to `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 4):

Use another collection for the additions and combine them at the end.

```
List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
collection.add(...)
...
List<Integer> tempCollection = new ArrayList<>();    
for (Integer lobId: collection ) {
     ..
     if (someCondition) {
         tempCollection.add(something); 
         break; 
     }
}

collection.addAll(tempCollection);
```

Comment: The interface documentation of iterator can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html Knowing it is part of any basic java certificate. Dublicating the list is not only bad practise, it also leads to major security flaws.

Comment: @Hannes I'm not duplicating the list

Answer (score 2):

`ConcurrentModificationException` basically means that you're iterating over a `Collection` with one `iterator` (albeit implicitly defined by your enhanced `for` loop) and invalidating it on the fly by changing the `Collection` itself.
You can avoid this by doing the modifications via the **same`iterator`**:

```
List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
ListIterator<Integer> iter = collection.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
     Integer currVal = iter.next();
     if (someCondition) {
         iter.add(something); // Note the addition is done on iter
         break; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Since when does Iterator have an add method? Only ListIterator has an add method. Change your Iterator in ListIterator and this answer is correct. Since user01 stated he has a List, this will work. If he's using another Collection, then it won't work.

Comment: @ogregoire indeed, you are correct. Wasn't paying attention. Fixed accordingly - thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

if I understand you right, you want to iterate over the list , if some condition , you want to break the iteration , and an item and start fresh .

In the case do this:

```
   List<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<>();
   boolean flag = false;
   Integer item = 
    for (Integer lobId: collection) {
         ..
         if (someCondition) {
             flag = true;
             item = something; 
             break; 
         }
    }

   if (flag){
      collection.add(item);
   }
```

if someone else is going to change the list outside out loop  - you will need to sync those access - read [iterator thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847939/is-list-iterator-thread-safe) , and use  the other answers here like copying the list or some other copy on write

Answer (score -1):

Don't use for each, use the good old

```
for(int i=0; i<collection.size();i++)
```

Comment: It doesn't answer his question.

Comment: you mean this question? 'How could I possibly do something like above avoiding ConcurrentModificationException?'

Comment: Yes. He asked about iterating a `Collection` whilst also adding and removing elements sometimes. A standard for-loop would not even work in this case as variable `i` implies that you are retrieving based on an index (like within a list), and not all collections necessarily support that (consider a `Set`). Furthermore, adding or removing an element while iterating using said loop would throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` in most cases, which creates the problem that he was asking about in the first place.

Comment: 1. ok, my bad, i assumed he/she was iterating over a list, must have been because he explicitly states that he's iterating over an arrayList, and 2. no, in this case, you get a ConcurrentModificationException because the foreach loop uses the iterator of the list, and being an arrayList, it's a fail-fast one,  with my answer you don't get to use the iterator so you don't get the exception

Comment: and 3. it's not nice to modify an arrayList inside a loop like this, but then again, he explicitly states that after modifying the list, he breaks the loop, so it does no harm. I think this and @Mureinick are the best answers so far, some people should try reading before clicking.

Comment: Your answer is pretty incomplete, but the OP is indeed **appending** items to an **ArrayList**. So the `Listterator` solutions does something different. @MartinTuskevicius: The calls his variable `collection`, but initializes it as an `ArrayList`. Anyway, this answer is more correct than using `ListIterator` as it maintains the list order.

Comment: When the collection is an ArrayList, a for loop based on the index can work. Adding elements at the end of the list won't cause problems. If you remove an element at or before position i, decrement i by 1 so the iteration won't skip any elements.